# Android kotlin object detection roadmap

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, object-detection

A company gave me this task..

can anyone help me with it's roadmap

User opens the app

Camera is open

Camera detects objects and when user captures a picture of the object the image is sent to a fragment.
What library should i use for object detection?!

I mainly wanna know how to detect objects with the rear camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use TensorFlow for this task, you can check this link for guidance: [Object detection with Android](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/android/tutorials/object_detection#run_predictions). Also, you can find more models on this site which you can choose what to use for this task: [Tensorflow Hub](https://tfhub.dev) Also there is a tutorial by Google that teaches how to use object detection for an image, Google has so many Codelabs which you can learn how to use Tensorflow for your project, for example: [Build and deploy a custom object detection model with TensorFlow Lite (Android)](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/tflite-object-detection-android#0).